# How to check if a query already has only one where clause in rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, regex, database, postgresql

I'm working on building queries dynamically, based on a base query.

`base_query` is a string column in the DB.

For example, the user will input a base query `select * from users`.

In this query, I will add a `where` clause in the backend like this `select * from users where user id=1`.

On the UI we will return all the details related to the user with `id=1`.

The base query can not have `where` because I'm appending it in the backend. It will break the query if there are two `where` clauses. But it should accept the `where` with a `subquery`.

How can I validate a base query string?

It can have `subquery` with `where` but not at the end because it would break in the back-end.

For example,

**Valid query:**

1. `select count(*) from users;`
2. `select count(*) from (select * from users where id > 2) as u`

**Not a valid:** ``

1. `select * from users where id=1;`

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the user inputs will be received by the server as a string, so you can just use the string library to check if your string has a sub string `where`.

Something like

`str.scan(/#{where}/i)`

should do the trick and will ignore case